# How can i show a javascript Alert message from code behind(C#) after an AJAX call

Tags: ajax

In the ContinueClick code it gives an error "The control must be in the control tree
of a page. Parameter name: control"

```
$('#' + btnContinueClientID).click(function () 
{
ToShowAlertMessage()
}

function ToShowAlertMessage(controlName, segmentID, passengerID) {
        $.post("/JQuerySeatMap.aspx",
    { ClickedControl: controlName,
        str1: str1,
        str2: str2,
            str3: str3
    },

public string ContinueClick(string str1, string str2, string str3)
{
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ClientScript", "alert('Alert   
 Message.');, true);
}


But in the ContinueClick code it gives an error "The control must be in the control tree    
of a page. Parameter name: control"
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this would be to put the `alert` inside the JS callback, rather than register the `ScriptManager` to call some client-side code.

```
$.post("/JQuerySeatMap.aspx",
{ ClickedControl: controlName,
    str1: str1,
    str2: str2,
    str3: str3
}, function(data) {
    alert('Alert Message.');
});
```